# BezierCurve in EdgeShapeFunction fails when used on multiedges graph

Tags: graphs-and-networks, replacement, splines

I would like to create a network graph with curved edges. To do this, I wrote this function:

```
edgeFun[pts_, e_] := Module[{controlPts},
     controlPts = pts /. {a_, b_} :> {a, {a[[1]] + .1 b[[1]], a[[2]]},
                                         {a[[1]] + 0.1 b[[1]], b[[2]]}, b}; 
      BezierCurve[controlPts]
];
```

With no multiedges the `edgeFun` function works fine:

```
pts = {1 -> 2, 2 -> 3, 3 -> 1};
Graph[pts, VertexLabels -> Placed["Name", Center], EdgeShapeFunction -> edgeFun]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

But when I want to create a network with multiple edges (note `1 -> 2` and `2 -> 1`, *Mathematica* complains and the graph is pinked out:

```
pts1 = {1 -> 2, 2 -> 3, 3 -> 1, 2 -> 1};
Graph[pts1, VertexLabels -> Placed["Name", Center], EdgeShapeFunction -> edgeFun]
```

> ```
> Part::partd: "Part specification 0.496922[[1]] is longer than depth of object"
> ```

Does anyone know how to solve this problem?

Comment: The problem is, that for loops `Graph` is greating curved edges so those are not just `{point1, point2}` type `Lines`. At the end the problem is your replacement rule which is not well suited for those lists.

Comment: See [built-in automatic method using `"EdgeLayout"`](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/81394/89) that curves edges.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As I said in my comment:

The problem is that for loops, `Graph` is creating curved edges. Therefore, the edges are not just `{point1, point2}` type `Lines`. Ultimately your problem is your replacement rule, which is not well suited for such lists.

You can check that the `EdgeShapeFunction` is passed all the points, not only the initial ones:

```
pts = {1 -> 2, 2 -> 1, 2 -> 3, 3 -> 1};
Graph[pts, VertexLabels -> Placed["Name", Center], 
           EdgeShapeFunction -> ((Print[Short[#]]; Line[#1]) &)]
```

> ```
> {{0.496922,0.},{0.518107,0.109873},<<15>>,{0.999994,0.864245}}
> {{0.999994,0.864245},{0.978809,0.754372},<<15>>,{0.496922,0.}}
> {{0.999994,0.864245},{0.,0.867795}}
> {{0.,0.867795},{0.496922,0.}}
> ```

So, keeping that in mind, you can write the proper function, for example:

```
edgeFun[pts_, e__] := BezierCurve[{#, # - {0, 1}, #2} & @@ pts[[{1, -1}]]];

pts = {1 -> 2, 2 -> 1, 2 -> 3, 3 -> 1};
Graph[pts, VertexLabels -> Placed["Name", Center], EdgeShapeFunction -> edgeFun]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: Hi,Thanks for your reply. unfortunately, when I copy your code exactly as you wrote it, in my notenbook, I get the same complains and the graph is pinked out. Is it possible that it has something to do with my configuration:"Version" -> 
     "9.0 Home Edition for Microsoft Windows (64-bit) 
    "MachineType" -> "PC", "OperatingSystem" -> "Windows", 
    "ProcessorType" -> "x86-64", "Language" -> "English"

Comment: @MichielvanMens When I'm copying the last `codeblock` there is no error, only the plot as the one above. Try to reset the kernel or `ClearAll[edgeFun]` earlier.

Comment: @MichielvanMens does it help?

Comment: with pattern: edgeFun[{a_, ___, b_}, e_] := 
  BezierCurve[{a, {a[[1]] + .1 b[[1]], a[[2]]}, {a[[1]] + .1 b[[1]], 
     b[[2]]}, b}];

Comment: It Works. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 3):

An alternative is to use `"CurvedArc"` as the `EdgeShapeFunction`:

```
Graph[pts, VertexLabels -> Placed["Name", Center], VertexSize -> Medium, 
 EdgeShapeFunction -> GraphElementData[{"CurvedArc", "Curvature" -> -3/2}]]
```

[image]

```
Graph[pts1, VertexLabels -> Placed["Name", Center], VertexSize -> Medium, 
 EdgeShapeFunction -> GraphElementData[{"CurvedArc", "Curvature" -> -3/2}]]
```

[image]

Comment: Very under-rated answer!

Comment: I cannot find documentation for `GraphElementData`

Comment: @Themis, unfortunately, it is not documented.

Answer (score 2):

Just to be redundant, I think your patterns need tuning for the extra points sent by multiple edges:

```
{{0, 0}, {1, 2}} /. {a_, b_} :> {"a is " <> ToString[a], "b is " <> ToString[b]}
```

> {"a is {0, 0}", "b is {1, 2}"}

```
{{0, 0}, {1, 1}, {2, 2}, {3, 3}} /. {a_, b_} :> {"a is " <> ToString[a], "b is " <> ToString[b]}
```

> {{"a is 0", "b is 0"}, {"a is 1", "b is 1"}, {"a is 2", 
>         "b is 2"}, {"a is 3", "b is 3"}}