# Edge Styling in Graph Funciton

Tags: graphs-and-networks, visualization

Inside the `Graph[]` command, is there a way to "spread" multiedges apart? if you have many edges they get quite close together.

Specifically, I have many small graphs with multiedges which will themselves be vertices on a large graph, and I would like to be able to see all the edges even when the graph is small.

Comment: Don't know if there is a GraphLayout which does this but at the end you could play with `EdgeShapeFunction` see e.g.: [66784](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/66784/5478). Anyway, could you provide something to working with? That is a small multiedge graph?

Comment: Thanks! I like this, except that I can't keep the middle edge "flat" since you specify the curvature for all edges between a particular two vertices simultaneously:  Graph[{1, 2}, {1 <-> 2, 1 <-> 2, 1 <-> 2}, 
  EdgeShapeFunction -> {1 <-> 2 -> 
     GraphElementData[{"CurvedArc", "Curvature" -> 1}]}]

Answer (score 1):

I do not know if there is an easy way with `Graph`, unfortunately.

The older (and deprecated) [`GraphPlot`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/GraphPlot.html) has this feature through the [`MultiedgeStyle`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/MultiedgeStyle.html) option.

One way with `Graph`, which only works for *some* graph layouts, is the following:

```
Graph[{1 -> 2, 1 -> 2, 1 -> 2, 1 -> 2}, EdgeShapeFunction ->
  Function[{pts, edge},
   Module[
    {stretch = 2, first = First[pts], last = Last[pts], med, mid},
    med = Median[pts];
    mid = (first + last)/2;
    Arrow@BezierCurve[{first, mid + stretch (med - mid), last}]
    ]
   ]]
```

Set the `stretch` factor to spread the multi-edges.

This method assumes that multi edges are simple arcs from the starting point to the endpoint. With `GraphLayout`s such as `"LayeredDigraphEmbedding"`, or with explicitly set `"EdgeLayout"`s, this is not the case.  Thus if you use this in a general function, I recommend setting the `GraphLayout` explicitly to something which generally works well, such as `"SpringElectricalEmbedding"`.

Answer (score 1):

In versions 13.+ (perhaps in older versions too) the option `GraphLayout` has a suboption `"MultiEdgeDistance"`:

```
Graph[{1 -> 2, 1 -> 2, 1 -> 2, 1 -> 2}, 
 GraphLayout -> {"MultiEdgeDistance" -> .5}]
```

[image]

```
Grid[{#}, Dividers -> All] & @ Table[
  Graph[{1 -> 2, 1 -> 2, 1 -> 2, 1 -> 2, 2 -> 3}, 
     ImageSize -> Small, 
     GraphLayout -> {"MultiEdgeDistance" -> d}, 
     PlotLabel -> "MultiEdgeDistance" -> d], 
  {d, Subdivide[4]}]
```

[image]