# Add curved edges to existing Graph

Tags: graphs-and-networks

I have a graph where I want to add edges which should be visible therefore they must be curved sometimes.
[image]

Here the one edge on the left (from `c2cd` [top left] to `d5de` [bottom left]) should be curved.

My current code:

```
    g := Graph[{"s" -> "s1sc", "s1sc" ->  "s2sa", "s2sa" -> "s3sb", 
   "s1sc" -> "s3fj", "s3fj" -> "s5gk", "s3fj" -> "f9hd", 
   "s1sc" -> "g8ie", "f" -> "f3fj", "f3fj" -> "f5gk", 
   "f5gk" -> "f9hd", "f5gk" -> "g6gc", "f3fj" -> "g8ie", 
   "a" -> "a2cd", "a2cd" -> "a2ae", "a2ae" -> "a6ad", 
   "a2ae" -> "a9hd", "a2cd" -> "c8ie", "g" -> "g5gk", 
   "g5gk" -> "g6gc", "g5gk" -> "g8ie", "g5gk" -> "h9hd", 
   "c" -> "c2cd", "c2cd" -> "c8ie", "c2cd" -> "h9hd", "k" -> "k1ki", 
   "k1ki" -> "k3kt", "k3kt" -> "k6kj", "k1ki" -> "k8ie", 
   "k1ki" -> "h9hd", "b" -> "b2bc", "b2bc" -> "b8ie", 
   "b2bc" -> "h9hd", "h" -> "h8ie", "h8ie" -> "h9hd", "d" -> "d5de", 
   "d5de" -> "d8ie", "i" -> "i8ie", "c2cd" -> "d5de"}, 
  EdgeStyle -> {("s1sc" -> "s2sa") -> Green, ("s2sa" -> "s3sb") -> 
     Green, ("k1ki" -> "k3kt") -> Green, ("k3kt" -> "k6kj") -> 
     Green, ("a2ae" -> "a6ad") -> Green, ("g5gk" -> "g6gc") -> 
     Green, ("f5gk" -> "g6gc") -> Green, ("s" -> "s1sc") -> 
     Gray, ("f" -> "f3fj") -> Gray, ("a" -> "a2cd") -> 
     Gray, ("g" -> "g5gk") -> Gray, ("c" -> "c2cd") -> 
     Gray, ("k" -> "k1ki") -> Gray, ("b" -> "b2bc") -> 
     Gray, ("h" -> "h8ie") -> Gray, ("d" -> "d5de") -> 
     Gray, ("i" -> "i8ie") -> Gray}, VertexLabels -> "Name", 
  DirectedEdges -> True, 
  VertexCoordinates -> {{10.708343333333334`, -0.7083433333333335`}, \
{10.708343333333334`, -1.7083433333333335`}, {11.708343333333334`, \
-2.7083433333333335`}, {11.708343333333334`, -3.7083433333333335`}, \
{10.708343333333334`, -2.7083433333333335`}, {10.708343333333334`, \
-3.7083433333333335`}, {9.708343333333334`, -3.7083433333333335`}, \
{8.708343333333334`, -2.7083433333333335`}, {9.708343333333334`, \
-0.7083433333333335`}, {9.708343333333334`, -1.7083433333333335`}, \
{9.708343333333334`, -2.7083433333333335`}, {7.7083433333333335`, \
-3.7083433333333335`}, {2.7083433333333335`, -0.7083433333333335`}, \
{2.7083433333333335`, -1.7083433333333335`}, {2.7083433333333335`, \
-2.7083433333333335`}, {2.7083433333333335`, -3.7083433333333335`}, \
{3.7083433333333335`, -3.7083433333333335`}, {0.7083433333333335`, \
-2.7083433333333335`}, {7.7083433333333335`, -0.7083433333333335`}, \
{7.7083433333333335`, -1.7083433333333335`}, {4.7083433333333335`, \
-2.7083433333333335`}, {0.7083433333333335`, -0.7083433333333335`}, \
{0.7083433333333335`, -1.7083433333333335`}, {5.7083433333333335`, \
-0.7083433333333335`}, {5.7083433333333335`, -1.7083433333333335`}, \
{6.7083433333333335`, -2.7083433333333335`}, {6.7083433333333335`, \
-3.7083433333333335`}, {5.7083433333333335`, -2.7083433333333335`}, \
{3.7083433333333335`, -0.7083433333333335`}, {3.7083433333333335`, \
-1.7083433333333335`}, {3.7083433333333335`, -2.7083433333333335`}, \
{4.7083433333333335`, -0.7083433333333335`}, {4.7083433333333335`, \
-1.7083433333333335`}, {0.7083433333333335`, -5.125030000000001`}, \
{0.7083433333333335`, -6.125030000000001`}, {0.7083433333333335`, \
-7.125030000000001`}, {6.916686666666667`, -5.625030000000001`}, \
{6.916686666666667`, -6.625030000000001`}}]
```

Is it possible to make the edge curved explicitly? I know that sometimes mathematica make an edge curved on it's own...

Comment: related: [34181](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/34181/5478)

Answer (score 8):

```
SetProperty[{g, "c2cd" -> "d5de"}, EdgeShapeFunction -> 
 ({Arrowheads[{Large}], Arrow[GraphElementData[{"CurvedArc", "Curvature" -> -3}][##]]} &)]
```

[image]

To make all edges curved:

```
SetProperty[g, EdgeShapeFunction ->
 ({Arrowheads[{Large}], Arrow[GraphElementData[{"CurvedArc", "Curvature" -> -1}][##]]} &)]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: Very nice, looks much better than the other attempt!

Answer (score 2):

This is a silly little hack, but maybe it will help here.  You can make a function that draws a half-circle between two points, and use that as your `EdgeShapeFunction`,

```
ef = (Arrow[
    CirclePoints[
      Mean@#1[[{1, -1}]], {(EuclideanDistance @@ #1[[{1, -1}]])/2, 
       VectorAngle[Subtract @@ #1[[{1, -1}]], {1, 0}]}, 
      100][[;; 51]]] &);
```

You could give the option `, EdgeShapeFunction -> ef` to the `Graph` if you like, getting this output:

[image: Mathematica graphics]

But if you only want a specific edge to be modified, then replace the line `"c2cd" -> "d5de"` in your list of edges with `Property["c2cd" -> "d5de", EdgeShapeFunction -> ef]`, resulting in this:

[image: Mathematica graphics]

If you've already got `g` defined as the graph, then you could achieve the same result via

```
SetProperty[g, 
 EdgeShapeFunction -> {DirectedEdge["c2cd", "d5de"] -> ef}]
```

Comment: Thanks but I hoped there is a more automatic function because I will need a lot of different curves.

Comment: There are a lot of different graph layouts, but you don't have access to them because you've specified the coordinates yourself.

Comment: Yeah I want the graph twice (one without these edges) and want them to look nearly the same :D Probably I will use only a part of it for better readability :)

Comment: Are you looking for an automated way to find out which edges are going through other vertices that aren't part of the edge, which is the case for this particular edge?

Comment: Yeah kind of and curve them in an automated way. I have high standards but well it's mathematica ...

Comment: I don't really see what is preventing you from automating this yourself.....

Comment: That is a different way of interpreting the word automated. But yes I think that might be an option. Thanks for your answer.