# How to control size of self loops in Graph?

Tags: graphs-and-networks, visualization, style

Is there a way to control the size of self loops when rendering a `Graph`?

Example:

```
Graph[{1 -> 2, 1 -> 1}, VertexSize -> {1 -> 0.1, 2 -> 0.2},  PerformanceGoal -> "Quality"]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

How can I make the loop bigger or smaller?

I do not want to use a custom `EdgeShapeFunction`. Bult-in `EdgeShapeFunction`s are acceptable.

When using a user-defined edge shape function, the nice positioning of the arrowheads will be broken in the above graph.  When using a built-in one, such as `EdgeShapeFunction -> "CarvedArrow"`, everything is fine.  Perhaps some of the builtin ones have an option to control the self loop size?  [Some do have options](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/124220/12), but they are undocumented.

`GraphPlot` has `SelfLoopStyle`. Is there anything for `Graph`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could define your own scaling arc function:

```
arcFunc[g_, r_: 1.5][list_, DirectedEdge[x_, x_]] :=

 With[{v = 
    DynamicLocation["VertexID$" <> ToString[VertexIndex[g, x]], 
     Automatic, Center]}, 
  Arrow[BezierCurve[
    Join[{v}, 
     ScalingTransform[r {1, 1}, list[[1]]][
      list[[{5, 8, 10, 16, 18, 21}]]], {v}], SplineDegree -> 7]]]

g = Graph[{1 -> 2, 1 -> 1}, VertexSize -> {1 -> 0.1, 2 -> 0.2}, 
  EdgeShapeFunction -> {x_ \[DirectedEdge] x_ :> arcFunc[g, 1.7]}, 
  PerformanceGoal -> "Quality"]
```

or

```
g = Graph[{1 -> 2, 1 -> 1}, VertexSize -> {1 -> 0.1, 2 -> 0.2}];
Graph[g, EdgeShapeFunction -> {x_ \[DirectedEdge] x_ :> 
    arcFunc[g, 1.7]}, PerformanceGoal -> "Quality"]
```

Comment: I did not know that it was possible to use a pattern when setting options such as `EdgeShapeFunction`.  I am referring to `x_ \[DirectedEdge] x_`. Do you know where this is documented?

Comment: @Szabolcs It's documented under scope in EdgeShapeFunction documentation page.

Comment: This answer does not work when I have specified EdgeLabels: `Graph[{1 -> 1, 1 -> 2}, 
 EdgeLabels -> {(1 -> 1) -> "E1", (1 -> 2) -> "E2"}, 
 EdgeShapeFunction -> {x_ \[DirectedEdge] x_ :> arcFunc[g, 1.7]}]`. How could I resolve this?

Comment: @Hotschke this function need to set PerformanceGoal -> "Quality". g = Graph[{1 -> 1, 1 -> 2}, 
  EdgeLabels -> {(1 -> 1) -> "E1", (1 -> 2) -> "E2"}, 
  EdgeShapeFunction -> {x_ \[DirectedEdge] x_ :> arcFunc[g, 1.7]}, 
  PerformanceGoal -> "Quality"]

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It works now. However, I do not know why this has something to do with `PerformanceGoal`. I cannot find an explanation in the documentation under `EdgeShapeFunction` or `PerformanceGoal`. Can you give me a hint?

Comment: @Hotschke argFunc uses DynamicLocation which is only showed up when PerformanceGoal set to "Quality".

Comment: Thanks for your help. DynamicLocation seems to be undocumented?

Comment: @Hotschke no, that is not documented

Comment: Why do you know about this? Are there additional resources I do not know about?

Comment: @Hotschek search DynamicLocation here than you could get all the information

Comment: :-) https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/155157/dynamiclocation-usage