# DynamicLocation usage

Tags: graphics, front-end, dynamic, undocumented

### Background

`DynamicLocation` can be very useful:

```
LocatorPane[Dynamic@x,
  Graphics[
    { EdgeForm @ Thick, FaceForm @ None, Rectangle[BoxID -> "box"]
    , Arrow[{Dynamic[x], DynamicLocation["box", Automatic]}]
    }
    , PlotRange -> 2
  ]
]
```

[image]

but I don't know much about it. It was introduced to me by Szabolcs somewhere around this topic: [Find inset bounding box in plot coordinates](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/140098/5478). It is extensively used in `Graph` related plots, e.g. to make edge arrows pointing neatly to the edge of a vertex shape.

As shown above it can be used to specify position in `Graphics` with respect to primitives' boxes. So we can point e.g. Arrow to a Recangle, without knowing it's position, which was previously marked by `BoxID`. ([see more: BoxID in InputField focus](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/81352/5478))

It also accepts more arguments which can e.g. automatically point to the closest point on marked primitive. Something that would normally cost us calling the kernel for some region related procedures.

### Question

But what arguments does it accept and what do they do? What are possible pitfalls in using it?

### What did I try?

From Graph related documentation pages I extracted only examples with:

```
DynamicLocation[id_String, Automatic | None, _alignmentSpec]}]
```

Where `alignmentSpec` is `{Left, Center}` etc.

I also noticed that its behavior depends of parent graphics primitive (not id's owner):

```
LocatorPane[Dynamic@x,
 Graphics[
  {EdgeForm@Thick, FaceForm@None, Rectangle[BoxID -> "box"]
   , Rectangle[Dynamic[x], DynamicLocation["box", Automatic]]
   , Arrow[{Dynamic[x], DynamicLocation["box", Automatic]}]

   }
  , PlotRange -> 2]
 ]
```

So the same DynamicLocation is points to different positions for Rectangle and Arrow, keep that in mind in your answer.

Comment: I note your example can apply to `Polygon`,but could you give me a `Circle` example?

Comment: This looks like an interesting question, but I would appreciate a little background on the undocumented functions and options you using.

Comment: @m_goldberg done, not so much more but it is all I know.

Comment: @Kuba I bet they only use things that can be modeled as rectangular boxes. `Inset` works great.

Comment: @yode Circle example is now solved, see https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/155237/5478

Answer (score 13):

So I did a scrape of all the installation files (nb, m, tr) and this is what I got:

```
$dynamicLocationDump=CloudImport["https://www.wolframcloud.com/objects/b3m2a1/dynamic_location_dump.mx"];
```

It's an `Association` of files and what was found there. All of the files are to be ref pages, many for `Combinatorica`.

If we look at *all* of the stuff that's scraped, this is what we find:

```
$specs = Cases[$dynamicLocationDump // Values, _DynamicLocation, \[Infinity]] //
  DeleteDuplicatesBy[Rest]

{DynamicLocation["VertexID$1", Automatic, Center], 
 DynamicLocation["VertexID$1", None, Center], 
 DynamicLocation["EdgeLabelID$2", Automatic, Scaled[0.5]], 
 DynamicLocation["VertexID$2", Automatic, Right], 
 DynamicLocation["VertexID$4", Automatic, Top], 
 DynamicLocation["VertexID$1", Automatic, {Right, Top}], 
 DynamicLocation["VertexID$1", Automatic, Left], 
 DynamicLocation["VertexID$5", Automatic, {Right, Bottom}], 
 DynamicLocation["VertexID$6", Automatic, Bottom], 
 DynamicLocation["EdgeLabelID$1", Automatic, Scaled[0.9]], 
 DynamicLocation["EdgeLabelID$4", Automatic, Scaled[0.965]], 
 DynamicLocation["EdgeLabelID$5", Automatic, Scaled[1]], 
 DynamicLocation["EdgeLabelID$1", Automatic, Scaled[0.]], 
 DynamicLocation["EdgeLabelID$1", Automatic, Scaled[1.]], 
 DynamicLocation["EdgeLabelID$2", Automatic, Scaled[0.96]], 
 DynamicLocation["EdgeLabelID$2", Automatic, Scaled[0.955]], 
 DynamicLocation["EdgeLabelID$1", Automatic, Scaled[0]], 
 DynamicLocation["EdgeLabelID$1", Automatic, Scaled[1/4]], 
 DynamicLocation["EdgeLabelID$1", Automatic, Scaled[1/3]], 
 DynamicLocation["EdgeLabelID$1", Automatic, Scaled[1/2]], 
 DynamicLocation["VertexID$1", Automatic, {Left, Bottom}], 
 DynamicLocation["VertexID$1", Automatic, {Left, Top}], 
 DynamicLocation["EdgeLabelID$1", Automatic, Scaled[0.6]], 
 DynamicLocation["EdgeLabelID$3", Automatic, Scaled[0.3]], 
 DynamicLocation["EdgeLabelID$1", Automatic, Scaled[0.4]]}
```

This suggest you pretty much hit everything. Let's just do one last quick look:

```
LocatorPane[Dynamic@x,
 Graphics[{
   EdgeForm@Thick, FaceForm@None, Rectangle[BoxID -> "box"],
   {Arrow[{Dynamic[x], #}], Red, 
       Text[HoldForm[#], Offset[{1, RandomInteger[{-20, 0}]}, #]]} & /@

          DeleteDuplicatesBy[
      Reverse@$specs, {#[[2]], Head[#[[3]]]} &] /. s_String -> "box"
   }, PlotRange -> 2]]
```

[image: img]

Sorry about how tough that is to read. In any case, the only thing you didn't mention (I think) was the `Automatic | None` difference. `None` seems to mean the location within the parent primitive itself. `Automatic` appears to mean the nearest position along the primitive's boundary.

#### Update:

So I did a scrape of all the `GraphicsBox`-es and this is what I got:

```
$gbDynamicLocationDump=CloudImport["https://www.wolframcloud.com/objects/b3m2a1/graphics_dynamic_location_dump.mx"];
```

Then let's see what sort of things these `BoxID`s are assinged to:

```
Cases[Values@$gbDynamicLocationDump, _[___, 
   BoxID -> _, ___], \[Infinity]] // DeleteDuplicatesBy[Head]

{TagBox[DiskBox[{0., 0.}, 0.0203996], "DynamicName", 
  BoxID -> "VertexID$1"]}
```

So we can see they always use a `TagBox`. And, moreover, the `DiskBox` *is* supported, just we need to specify it right:

```
LocatorPane[Dynamic@x,
 Graphics[{
   TagBox[DiskBox[{0, 0}, .1], "DynamicName", BoxID -> "box"],
   Arrow[{Dynamic[x], DynamicLocation["box", Automatic]}]
   },
  PlotRange -> 1]
 ]
```

[image: disk-box]

I don't know how to do this in top-level primitives, though, so if someone else could chime in with that it'd be great.

#### Update 2:

Here're some of the scraped up supported box styles:

```
Cases[Values@$gbScrape, _[___, BoxID -> _, ___], \[Infinity]] // 
     Map[First] // Flatten // Map[Head] // DeleteDuplicates // 
 DeleteCases[
  Hue | GrayLevel | Thickness | RGBColor | EdgeForm | Arrowheads]

{DiskBox, StyleBox, TagBox, InsetBox, ArrowBox, RectangleBox, \
CircleBox, FilledCurveBox, DynamicBox, PointBox, PolygonBox, LineBox}
```

Which basically suggests everything is supported. Let's look at one example pulled directly from the scrape:

```
$edgeBox = 
  TagBox[StyleBox[
    ArrowBox[
     BezierCurveBox[{DynamicLocation["VertexID$1", Automatic, 
        Center], {0.16929929238168392`, -0.060834906748745296`}, \
{0.06631873896502918`, -0.24007829047418064`}, \
{-0.06588137300327365`, -0.2866769520693191`}, \
{-0.32874748131339104`, -0.01720980682360899`}, \
{-0.27888503732236586`, 0.11379416848298976`}, {-0.09714320225168427`,
         0.21229843426110356`}, 
       DynamicLocation["VertexID$1", Automatic, Center]}, 
      SplineDegree -> 7]], Arrowheads[Medium], StripOnInput -> False],
    "DynamicName", BoxID -> "EdgeLabelID$1"];

LocatorPane[Dynamic@x,
 Graphics[{
   $edgeBox,
   FaceForm[None], EdgeForm[Black],
   Rectangle[Dynamic[x], Dynamic[-x], BoxID -> "VertexID$1"],
   Arrow[{Dynamic[x], DynamicLocation["EdgeLabelID$1", Automatic]}]
   },
  PlotRange -> 1]
 ]
```

[image: bloop]

It gives a sense of how powerful this can be

Here's just one last trick we can do:

```
LocatorPane[Dynamic@x, 
 Graphics[{$edgeBox, FaceForm[None], EdgeForm[Black], 
   Rectangle[Dynamic[x], Dynamic[-x], BoxID -> "VertexID$1"],
   Arrow[{Dynamic[x],
     Dynamic[
      y = FE`Evaluate@DynamicLocation["EdgeLabelID$1", Automatic]
      ]}]}, PlotRange -> 1]]
```

It looks the same, but `y` takes on this weird `Perimeter` value that clearly the FE uses:

```
y

Perimeter[{{-0.351329, -0.306885}, {-0.351329, 0.612441}, {0.362441, 
   0.612441}, {0.362441, -0.306885}}, BezierCurve, Automatic, \
{{0.344778, -0.12389}, {0.319816, -0.116786}, {0.295984, -0.113405}, \
{0.273094, -0.113086}, {0.25097, -0.115206}, {0.229447, -0.119181}, \
{0.208376, -0.12447}, {0.187628, -0.130578}, {0.167094, -0.137054}, \
{0.146685, -0.143494}, {0.126339, -0.149538}, {0.106013, -0.154875}, \
{0.0856889, -0.159237}, {0.0653717, -0.162401}, {0.0450872, \
-0.164185}, {0.0248819, -0.164449}, {0.00482093, -0.16309}, \
{-0.0150137, -0.160042}, {-0.0345254, -0.155269}, {-0.0536057, \
-0.148769}, {-0.0721368, -0.140563}, {-0.0899945, -0.130697}, \
{-0.107052, -0.119236}, {-0.123181, -0.106261}, {-0.13826, \
-0.0918662}, {-0.152171, -0.0761518}, {-0.16481, -0.0592238}, \
{-0.176085, -0.0411881}, {-0.185923, -0.0221469}, {-0.194274, \
-0.00219502}, {-0.201111, 0.0185843}, {-0.206439, 
   0.0401228}, {-0.210292, 0.0623712}, {-0.212744, 
   0.0853023}, {-0.213904, 0.108915}, {-0.213925, 
   0.133236}, {-0.213007, 0.158324}, {-0.211393, 
   0.184273}, {-0.209381, 0.211212}, {-0.207318, 
   0.239309}, {-0.205605, 0.268775}, {-0.204699, 
   0.299858}, {-0.205113, 0.332852}, {-0.207418, 
   0.368093}, {-0.212241, 0.405961}, {-0.220266, 
   0.446879}, {-0.232235, 0.491312}, {-0.248944, 
   0.539763}, {-0.271242, 0.592778}}, 0.00277778]
```

Note that despite the naming, this is not [`Perimeter`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Perimeter.html) as if you try to evaluate you get an error. Rather this is something handled in the FE itself. But we can use it:

```
Quiet@Graphics[{
   Arrow[{
     {0, 0},
     Perimeter[{{-0.3513294816166106`, -0.3068850371721661`}, \
{-0.3513294816166106`, 0.6124405927277219`}, {0.3624405927277219`, 
        0.6124405927277219`}, {0.3624405927277219`, \
-0.3068850371721661`}}, BezierCurve, 
      Automatic, {{0.34477777777777785`, -0.12389020453117933`}, \
{0.3198158080521647`, -0.11678572885825483`}, {0.2959835781061064`, \
-0.1134049116935066`}, {0.27309421626600816`, -0.11308626362062549`}, \
{0.25097018105818075`, -0.1152060089894028`}, {0.22944697314491685`, \
-0.11918089795392665`}, {0.20837622351438345`, \
-0.12447042298528227`}, {0.18762818539739076`, -0.1305784672904533`}, \
{0.1670936573840974`, -0.13705441256912174`}, {0.14668536521371014`, \
-0.14349373354006323`}, {0.12633882971023885`, \
-0.14953810666883527`}, {0.10601274833736543`, \
-0.15487506052845523`}, {0.08568891784548616`, -0.1592371952247659`}, \
{0.06537172548398723`, -0.16240099831818505`}, {0.04508723625181282`, \
-0.16418528467353688`}, {0.024881903659384697`, \
-0.16444928766966216`}, {0.004820931474933732`, \
-0.1630904292005044`}, {-0.015013686071698618`, \
-0.1600417958993694`}, {-0.034525418154727594`, \
-0.15526934901805498`}, {-0.05360571781450374`, \
-0.1487688953925486`}, {-0.07213678154294184`, \
-0.14056284692698964`}, {-0.08999452051924084`, \
-0.13069679602759415`}, {-0.10705171602283764`, -0.119235934418238`}, \
{-0.12318133155053107`, -0.10626134276939753`}, \
{-0.13825995416472048`, -0.09186617857214373`}, \
{-0.1521713375996978`, -0.07615178968888592`}, \
{-0.16481001965293363`, -0.0592237810125657`}, \
{-0.17608498638829806`, -0.04118806166599455`}, \
{-0.18592335567815732`, -0.02214690017303507`}, \
{-0.1942740526112855`, -0.002195015033320563`}, {-0.2011114492935343`,
         0.018584271867786717`}, {-0.20643894156819753`, 
        0.040122791582304446`}, {-0.21029243518301577`, 
        0.06237116672410781`}, {-0.21274371393075708`, 
        0.08530230496307703`}, {-0.2139036622903172`, 
        0.10891471995722232`}, {-0.2139253150952799`, 
        0.13323565229107964`}, {-0.2130067067568755`, 
        0.15832396298869578`}, {-0.21139349256828177`, 
        0.18427277216948668`}, {-0.20938131461720355`, 
        0.21121181541528777`}, {-0.2073178848336742`, 
        0.23930949041688565`}, {-0.20560475770002262`, 
        0.2687745664683503`}, {-0.2046987651499378`, 
        0.2998575293774527`}, {-0.20511308618358182`, 
        0.3328515343604829`}, {-0.20741792372567824`, 
        0.3680929394897675`}, {-0.21224076125353575`, 
        0.405961392262186`}, {-0.22026617172192897`, 
        0.44687944185699774`}, {-0.23223515131178862`, 
        0.4913116496512662`}, {-0.24894395052962903`, 
        0.5397631705612203`}, {-0.2712423751846815`, 
        0.592777777777778`}}, 0.002777777777777768`]
     }]
   }]
```

[image: permi box]

Comment: I asked also because I failed to use it with `Offset`, which would be very useful, and blindly tried putting `{ox, oy}` inside. Couldn't catch a pattern or even the difference for the first or the second argument unless it was just `Automatic`. Thanks for digging.

Comment: @Kuba I'm currently waiting for a scrape that will pull all of the `GraphicsBox`-es themselves and maybe there'll be something there where we can pull the different primitives supported.

Comment: @Kuba the scrape paid off. And it only had to look through ~2000 of the 18000 files.

Comment: Nice, I guess `DynamicNamespace` is related to `"DynamicName"`.

Comment: @Kuba I'm guessing so. I don't really know. I tried to figure out `DynamicNamespace` a while ago and it was painful.

Comment: It seems it can be used to avoid ids conflicts: `LocatorPane[Dynamic@x, Graphics[{
   TagBox[DiskBox[{1, 1}, .1], "DynamicName", BoxID -> "box"],
   DynamicNamespace[{
     TagBox[DiskBox[{0, 0}, .1], "DynamicName", BoxID -> "box"], 
     Arrow[{Dynamic[x], DynamicLocation["box", Automatic]}]
     }]}, PlotRange -> 1]]`. Looks like we are getting somewhere with it finally.

Comment: @Kuba interesting. That is useful. It's also used all over the `WolframAlphaClient` stuff if I remember correctly. It's clearly a localization scheme, but I couldn't figure out the particulars.

Comment: @Kuba [this](https://www.wolframcloud.com/objects/user-affd7b1c-ecb6-4ccc-8cc4-4d107e2bf04a/dynamic_namespace_dump.mx) is what I got from a scrape for `DynamicNamespace`

Comment: You are a crazy man. :)

Comment: @b3m2a1 There should be an option to convert DynamicLocation into absolute coordinates as graphs usually don't contain DynamicLocation at all. Failed to find it though. Any ideas?

Comment: @Kuba I'm sure it's handled through that Perimeter thing. How to go from that to an explicit position I don't know, though. One thing worth noting is some of the old Graph code that used DynamicLocation doesn't any more. What happens if you use "DynamicToLiteral" on a DynamicLocation containing Graphics?

Comment: @b3m2a1 ah, it is a token, I knew there was something like that, I forgot and was confused searching for a symbol. Now you told me the name I remember, and yes, it works with DynamicLocation leaving everything else intact. Would be nice to have something more precise.

Comment: @Kuba you can also use the front end packet ``FrontEnd`NotebookDynamicToLiteral``, but it requires a `CellObject` or `BoxObject` (I mean, it's typesetting, so it can't do much else). Unfortunately it replaces the object, though.

Comment: @b3m2a1 yep, though I could live with working with boxes, it can accept BoxData :(

Comment: @b3m2a1 I was just about to play with this again, but your cloud object expired...

Comment: @M.R. what a pain. Do you mean `$dynamicLocationDump`? I can see if I have a local cache of it...