# How to get this Europe map using Mathematica?

Tags: graphics, geographics

I need to generate a Europe map with given lattitue limit and longitute limit as shown in the attached figure. I want the map to be more detailed and colorful (attractive).

Furthermore, if I want to put some transparent cicles (with border latitute and longitude) on the map, how can i do it. Transparent circles means the map on the back should still be visible.

[image: Map of Europe]

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: Have you even looked "GeoProjection" in the documentation? You will find anything you need there. Even the transparent circles..

Comment: None of your previous questions' answers has been accepted. Don't they deserve it? Sometimes there are also unanswered comments asking for clarification. That may discourage people to answer your questions in future. Please take a tour: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Let me take a nap before I incorporate grid labels:

```
With[{range = { {25., 70.}, {-25., 45.}}}
, GeoGraphics[
    {
      {EdgeForm@Thick, FaceForm@None, GeoBoundsRegion[range]}
    }
  , GeoRange          -> range
  , GeoRangePadding   -> None
  , GeoProjection     -> {"Albers", "StandardParallels" -> {40, 60}}
  , GeoGridLines      -> {Range[30, 60, 15], Range[-15, 30, 15]}
  , GeoGridLinesStyle -> Directive[Dotted, GrayLevel[.7]]
  , ImagePadding      -> 10
  , GeoBackground     -> GeoStyling[{"Coastlines"
       , "Land" -> Gray, "Ocean" -> White, "Border" -> Black
    }]
  ]
 ]
```

[image]

Since there is no native way to specify `GeoTicks` etc. we need to generate them. One way is to

-> take our grid lines array ->  extract theirs intersection with bounding area -> convert to Albers -> and Inset labels with offset at those calculated positions...

...boring, let's try to incorporate [`DynamicLocation` and friends](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/155157/5478). Won't be shorter but maybe in future can be more general:

```
LabelGeoGridLines//ClearAll;
LabelGeoGridLines[x_,__]:=x;
LabelGeoGridLines[a:Annotation[{{dir__,lat:{__Line}},{dir2__,long:{__Line}}},"GeoGridLines",_],ranges_]:=Module[{temp}
, temp=a
; temp[[1,;;,2]]=MapIndexed[
    Function[{line,position}
    , With[{id=ToString[position]}
      , { DynamicName[line,id]
        , GridLabel[Extract[ranges,position],position[[1]]>1,id]
        }
      ]
   ]
  , temp[[1,;;,2]]
  , {2}
  ]
; temp
];

GridLabel[label_?NumericQ,True,id_]:=Text[Style[TextString[GeoPosition[{0,label}]]//StringSplit//Last, Black, 15],Offset[{0,-30},DynamicLocation[id,Automatic,Scaled[0]]]]
GridLabel[label_?NumericQ,False,id_]:=Text[Style[TextString[GeoPosition[{label,0}]]//StringSplit//First, Black, 15],Offset[{-30,0},DynamicLocation[id,Automatic,Scaled[0]]]]


 With[{range = { {25., 70.}, {-25., 45.}}, gridLines = {Range[30, 60, 15], Range[-15, 30, 15]}}
, GeoGraphics[
    {
      {EdgeForm@Thick, FaceForm@None, GeoBoundsRegion[range]}
    }
  , GeoRange          -> range
  , GeoRangePadding   -> None
  , GeoProjection     -> {"Albers", "StandardParallels" -> {40, 60}}
  , GeoGridLines      -> gridLines
  , GeoGridLinesStyle -> Directive[Dotted, GrayLevel[.7]]
  , PlotRangePadding  -> Scaled@.1
  , GeoBackground     -> GeoStyling[{"Coastlines"
       , "Land" -> Gray, "Ocean" -> White, "Border" -> Black
    }]
  , ImageSize -> 800  
  ] // Replace[
      #
    , a:Annotation[_,"GeoGridLines",_]:>LabelGeoGridLines[a,gridLines]
    , \[Infinity]
    ]& // DynamicNamespace

 ]
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: I'm wondering how could one display values of axis ticks on this sort of map.

Comment: @AndrzejGolonka see my edit.

Answer (score 4):

```
GeoGraphics[
  { Polygon[Entity["GeographicRegion", "Europe"]]
  , Red, GeoDisk[Entity["City", {"Warsaw", "Mazowieckie", "Poland"}], Quantity[377, "Kilometers"]]}
, GeoRange -> {{25, 70}, {-25, 45}}
, GeoProjection -> "Albers"
, GeoBackground -> GeoStyling["CountryBorders"]
, GeoGridLines -> Automatic
, GeoGridLinesStyle -> Directive[Thin, Dashed, Gray]
]
```

[image]

Comment: I'd recommend to use the projection {"Albers", "StandardParallels" -> {30, 60}}, to decrease distortion between those two standard parallels. In order to get the shape of the original example, use GeoRangePadding -> None.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/85533/discussion-on-answer-by-andrzej-golonka-how-to-get-this-europe-map-using-mathema).