# Detect the current PerformanceGoal in EdgeShapeFunction, as a condition for using DynamicLocation

Tags: graphs-and-networks, dynamic

The use of `DynamicLocation` is described in answers to the following questions:

- [DynamicLocation usage](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/155157/dynamiclocation-usage)
- [Framework behind Graph plots. DynamicNamespace and friends](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/155237/framework-behind-graph-plots-dynamicnamespace-and-friends)
- [How to create a custom EdgeShapeFunction whose arrowheads snap to vertices](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/215622/how-to-create-a-custom-edgeshapefunction-whose-arrowheads-snap-to-vertices)

The last of these describes `DynamicLocation` usage in an `EdgeShapeFunction`. However, the example there presumes that the `PerformanceGoal` option will be set to `"Quality"` whenever that `EdgeShapeFunction` is used.  If it is used with `PerformanceGoal->"Speed"`, the `DynamicLocation` entries become invalid coordinates.

I've been trying unsuccessfully to define a *flexible* `EdgeShapeFunction` that's aware of whether or not `DynamicLocation` will work in the current setting (i.e., whether the effective `PerformanceGoal` of its `Graph` is `"Quality"`). That's more or less how default edges are handled. So far though, I've found no satisfactory way to do this.

I've guessed that there might be some internal symbol or expression that could stand in for the appropriate coordinate form, but nothing has turned up. Therefore, I've tried making the `EdgeShapeFunction` conditional instead, which is easy enough, but *conditioned on what*?

My best attempt so far is the following, where `thisGraph` is passed explicitly into the `EdgeShapeFunction`:

```
ClearAll[eSF];

eSF[graph_Graph] := Function[{coords, edge},
   With[
    {
     dl1 = "VertexID$" <> ToString[VertexIndex[graph, edge[[ 1]]]],
     dl2 = "VertexID$" <> ToString[VertexIndex[graph, edge[[-1]]]]
     },
    
    If[PropertyValue[graph, PerformanceGoal] === "Quality",
     Arrow[{
       DynamicLocation[dl1, Automatic, Center],
       DynamicLocation[dl2, Automatic, Center]
       }],
     (* else assume "Speed" *)
     Arrow[coords]
     ]
    ]
   ];
```

```
Manipulate[
 thisGraph = Graph[{1 -> 2, 2 -> 3, 3 -> 1},
   VertexSize -> 0.3,
   VertexShapeFunction -> "ConcavePentagon",
   PerformanceGoal -> perf,
   EdgeShapeFunction :> eSF[thisGraph]
   ],
 {{perf, Automatic, "PerformanceGoal"}, {Automatic, "Quality", "Speed"}}
 ]
```

To avoid an explicit reference to the graph, I've considered pulling it out of `NotebookRead[EvaluationCell[]`, but that would be ugly and unreliable.

Is there a better way to accomplish this?

Comment: @kglr I'd like to eliminate the need to include thisGraph as an argument of eSF. That is, I need some way for eSF to discover the Graph it's being used in without having to tell it. That way, I can give eSF to others without extra instructions on how to make it work.

Comment: @kglr There are a variety of ways to solve this problem if non-idiomatic usage is accepted. I want to avoid this though, so that users can simply write `EdgeShapeFunction :> eSF` and have it work, regardless of other option settings.