# How to adjust the shape of some multiple edges of a graph separately?

Tags: plotting, graphs-and-networks

The graph we drew below using `tikz` is easy.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\tikzstyle{every node} = [inner sep=2pt,circle,draw]
    \node (0) at (-8, 4) {};
    \node (1) at (-2, 4) {};
    \draw (0) to (1);
    \draw [in=105, out=15, looseness=1.50] (0) to (1);
    \draw [bend left, looseness=1.25] (1) to (0);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

I'd like to draw this graph in Mathematica, but it seems that I can only control  one edge. (The other two  multiple  edges seem to be out of control)

```
g = Graph[{1 <-> 2, 1 <-> 2, 1 <-> 2}, VertexLabels -> All, 
 EdgeShapeFunction -> {1 <-> 2 -> {"CurvedEdge", "Curvature" -> -3}}]
```

[image]

PS: The top edge of the graph drawn by `tikz` is a **Bessel curve**. Can Mathematica specify the type of such a curve. I looked in the help documentation of `EdgeShapeFunction`and didn't see the type of curve selected.

- https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/EdgeShapeFunction.html

I know that Mathematica is not a drawing software. But sometimes I need to add some special shaped edges to the resulting graph, like the link below.

- [Add curved edges to existing Graph](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/124220/add-curved-edges-to-existing-graph/124230#124230)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Define custom edge function:

```
bezier[pts_, "Left", loose_ : .3] := bezier[pts, -30, 30 + 180, loose]

bezier[pts_, "Right", loose_ : .3] := bezier[pts, 30, -30 + 180, loose]

bezier[{x_, y_}, out_, in_, loose_ : .3] :=
 Block[{dir, p1, p2},
   dir = y - x;
   p1 = RotationTransform[out Degree, x][x + loose dir];
   p2 = RotationTransform[in Degree, y][y + loose dir];
   BezierCurve[{x,  p1, p2, y}]
 ]
```

Set graph with tagged edges:

```
Graph[{UndirectedEdge[1,2,1], UndirectedEdge[1,2,2], UndirectedEdge[
  1,2,3]}, VertexLabels -> {1 -> "1", 2 -> "2"}, 
 EdgeShapeFunction -> {UndirectedEdge[
    1,2,1] -> (bezier[#1[[{1, -1}]], 15, 105, .5] &), 
   UndirectedEdge[1,2,3] -> (bezier[#1[[{1, -1}]], "Left", .45] &)}, 
 VertexCoordinates -> {{-8, 4}, {-2, 4}}, 
 PlotTheme -> "IndexLabeled", VertexSize -> .05]
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

To control the edges separately, use distinct vertices that share their coordinates.

```
g = Graph[{1 <-> 2, 1 <-> 3, 1 <-> 4}, 
  VertexLabels -> {1 -> "1", 2 -> "2"}, 
  EdgeShapeFunction -> {
    1 <-> 2 -> {"CurvedEdge", "Curvature" -> 3}, 
    1 <-> 3 -> {"CurvedEdge", "Curvature" -> -2}},
  VertexCoordinates ->
   {{0, 0}, {1, 0}, {1, 0}, {1, 0}}]
```

[image]